Find $m \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $mX^4 + (1-3m)X^3 + 3(m-1)X^2 + (3-m)X - 1 = 0$ has only one root which is strictly greater than $1$.

Find $m \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $mX^4 + (1-3m)X^3 + 3(m-1)X^2 + (3-m)X - 1 = 0$ has only one root which is strictly greater than $1$.

I'm having trouble in solving this type of problems. I tried grouping the terms of this equation, which lead me to:
$mX(X^3 - 3X^2 + 3X - 1) + (X^3 - 3X^2 + 3X - 1) = 0$
Obviously that's $(X-1)^3 = 0$, so $X = 1$ should be a triple root to our equation, $\forall m \in \mathbb{R}$. Dividing our original equation to $(X-1)^3$, we get:
$mX + 1 = 0 \to X_4= -\frac{1}{m}$. So for $X_4 > 1$, $m$ has to lie between $(-1, 0)$. Plugging my equation into Desmos, I think it checks out? However, I have 5 answers to choose from and none of them match mine, the closest one is $m \in (-1, 1)$. I am wondering whether or not I have solved the problem correctly or if a different approach would work better!

$m=1/2$ does not work. I think nothing wrong here.

@BoweiTang Right!! I have to choose between $m \in (-\infty, -2), m \in (-2, -1/2), m \in (10, \infty), m\in (-1, 1), m \in (0, 2)$, none of these seem to be correct even if I plug them into a graphing calculator. Perhaps it's a mistake on their part.

You have to add only one REAL root. But it is not possible because if $a+bi$ is a root so is for $a-bi$ and you equation is of degre four (i. e. even)

Note that $m x^4+(1-3m)x^3+3(m-1)x^2+(3-m)x-1=(x-1)^3(m x+1)$

@Lozenges Yes, thank you! So isn't the fourth root $X_4 = -\frac{1}{m}$, from which we can find $m$ so $X_4 > 1$? My answer doesn't check out with the author's so I thought I must've been mistaken somewhere.

@Piquito To be honest I didn't even think about roots that could've been anything but real (which I should have :-)), but I got three real roots ($X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = 1$), so the fourth one has to be real aswell.

You have the correct answer: $(-1,0)$

One slight issue. Do not say the fourth root $=-1/m$ but rather, If $m \ne 0$ then the fourth root is $-1/m$
